# jQuery - Remove href attribute when checkbox is NOT checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attributes, href

I have a form with a "click here to accept terms and conditions" checkbox at the end before the "continue to checkout" link.

Using jQuery I want to remove the href attribute of the "continue shopping" link when the checkbox is NOT checked, and when a user selects the checkbox the href attribute is added back to the link.

The code I am using is below, but this is not working for some reason:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

if ($('input#tandc').is(':checked')) {
    jQuery("#continue_shopping").attr("href");
}
else
    jQuery("#continue_shopping").removeAttr("href").css({"opacity" : "0.3", "cursor":"default"});
    });
```

my html markup is something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tandc" value="tandc" id="tandc" required>
    I accept the <a href="/terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a>
</input>
<a id="continue_shopping" href="/store/shopping-cart/shipping/">Continue Shopping</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this. you should first set `continue shopping` disabled. logically right?

```
$(function(){
// should be disabled first, shouldnot it be?
$("#continue_shopping").removeAttr("href").css({"opacity" : "0.3", "cursor":"default"});
 $('#tandc').change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $("#continue_shopping").attr('href', '/store/shopping-cart/shipping/');
    } else {
        $("#continue_shopping").removeAttr("href").css({"opacity" : "0.3",  "cursor":"default"});
    }
  });
 });
```

**DEMO:** [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/7kakv/3/)

Comment: @HanletEscaño, yeah. i like it though

Comment: Yeah, I meant people should use it more :p

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1 - Use the `prop()` method.

```
$('#tandc').change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $("#continue_shopping").attr('href', '/store/shopping-cart/shipping/');
    } else {
        $("#continue_shopping").removeAttr("href").css({"opacity" : "0.3",  "cursor":"default"});
    }
  });
```

2 - Use a label, so that your users don't have to explicitly click the box:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tandc" value="tandc" id="tandc" required>
<label for="tandc">I accept the <a href="/terms-and-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a></label>

</input>
<a id="continue_shopping" href="#">Continue Shopping</a>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/8narS

Answer (score 0):

Is that code do what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tandc').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#continue_shopping").attr('href', '/store/shopping-cart/shipping/');
        } else {
            $("#continue_shopping").removeAttr("href").css({"opacity" : "0.3", "cursor":"default"});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this One:
**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/7kakv/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('#tandc').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#continue_shopping").attr('href', '/store/shopping-cart/shipping/').css({"opacity" : "1"});
        } else {
            $("#continue_shopping").removeAttr("href").css({"opacity" : "0.3", "cursor":"default"});
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set href as blank when check box is not checked.

```
if ($('input#tandc').is(':checked') == false) {
    jQuery("#continue_shopping").attr("href","");   
});
```